# Java regular expression for filename with one date and optional second date

Tags: java, regex, option-type

I have files like the following:

```
Foo_Apr17_bar_May18.csv
Foo_Mar16.csv
```

The first month will always be 3 letters, and the first year will always directly follow it with 2 digits.
The second month, if present, will also always be 3 letters, followed by 2 digits for the second year.
The second month and year may not be present, however.

How can I always capture the first month and year, and capture the second month and year if they are present?

This is not quite cutting it:

```
^.*_([\w]{3})([\d]{2}).*(([\w]{3})([\d]{2}))?.*.csv
```

Thanks!

**NOTE**

I am only allowed to pass a single regular expression without multiple matching. The code is not possible to alter. The regex is passed in via a configuration file, as are the field names. The field names are used as map keys.

Comment: Try [`^.*?_(\w{3})(\d{2})(?:.*(\w{3})(\d{2}))?\.csv$`](https://regex101.com/r/1Ax9gO/1)

Comment: you can easily solve things like this yourself with http://regex101.com ( or one of a dozen other interactive regex sites )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot chaneg the code, you may use

```
^.*?_(\w{3})(\d{2})(?:.*(\w{3})(\d{2}))?\.csv$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ax9gO/1).

The main point is that the `.*` should be put into an optional (made with a greedy `?` quantifier) group and the capturing groups that match the month and day must be compulsory inside that group.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, but as few as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(\w{3})` - Group 1: three word chars
- `(\d{2})` - Group 2: two digits
- `(?:.*(\w{3})(\d{2}))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of (so, at least 1 attempt will be made):

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
  - `(\w{3})` - Group 3: three word chars
  - `(\d{2})` - Group 4: two digits
- `\.csv` - a `.csv` string
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pattern with this regex `(\\w{3})(\\d{2})` :

```
String[] texts = {"Foo_Apr17_bar_May18.csv", "Foo_Mar16.csv"};
for (String text : texts) {

    String regex = "(\\w{3})(\\d{2})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("Month : " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(", Year : " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

output

```
Month : Apr, Year : 17
Month : May, Year : 18
Month : Mar, Year : 16
```

---

Edit

If you still want to use your regex you can fix it a little and use <kbd>[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKXgjv/1/)</kbd> :

```
.*?_(\w{3})(\d{2}).*?((\w{3})(\d{2}))?\.csv
```

But to not get null, you have to check if there are a the second part of not :

```
String regex = ".*?_(\\w{3})(\\d{2}).*?((\\w{3})(\\d{2}))?\\.csv";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {// Note I don't use while, Just If

    //Print first Month and Year
    System.out.print("Month : " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(", Year : " + matcher.group(2));

    //Then check if there are second Month and year or not
    if (matcher.group(3) != null) {

        //If yes, then print them
        System.out.print("Month : " + matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println(", Year : " + matcher.group(5));
    }

}
```

Same output as the previous result.

Comment: I am only allowed a single regular expression. The code is inflexible. The regex is passed in via a configuration file, as are the field names. The field names are used as map keys.

Comment: what did you mean *a single regular expression*?

Comment: The code that does the match is already written, and may not be altered.

Comment: You should add that information into your question. The @YCF_L code is perfect fine. You should also add some example of code of this source that can't be  changed so we can understand how the regex will be processed.

Comment: @chasse can you show us your code then, how we can know that there are a code?